# LaTeX3 - regex and new line

Tags: latex3, l3regex

I would like to replace each new line of an argument with `+` but I can't achieve this. Maybe a bad format for the argument...

What I am missing?

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn
    \str_new:N \l__crypto_code_str
    
    \NewDocumentCommand\cryptocode{m}{
        \str_set:Nn \l__crypto_code_str {#1}
        \regex_replace_all:nnN {\n} { + } \l__crypto_code_str
        \regex_replace_all:nnN {\s} { , } \l__crypto_code_str
        
        Result:
        \par
        \str_use:N \l__crypto_code_str
    }
\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}

\cryptocode{X H C M O N O Y J F O C D L D
T Z L O B O T O Q L O T H Y F
O M W M C L F V S R V L R G I
V Y C Y P O D Y R D X M I E Z
E K O D V J D E C A B R A E O
J B N X L V P R I L V A C A A
A A E V V G J C I R A Q U Y D
W L J S P B B G L L Y B A N I
G L O F C P Z V S K O G E L F
A E C L E A T O V P U D J J K
T N H M R T B R R T I C Z A A
O A G V A F W A R R O F R P B
R I J S N B F O L E O Z G E J
T Q R W A U T E O L N I D R W
G B J L E Y C G E C O P M X J}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The issue is that the newline characters get converted to spaces before `\str_set:Nn` sees them (by TeX's tokenisation rules). You'll have to use a multi-line verbatim argument (`+v` in `xparse`).

Comment: I'd use something like ``\\`` to mark the breaks, because text editors might get into the way and ruin your careful line breaking.

Comment: @egreg You are right but I'm playing with LaTeX" to learn a little more about it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following does what you want by using the `+v` argument type of `\NewDocumentCommand` (multi-line verbatim). This also uses `\str_replace_all:Nnn` instead of `\regex_replace_all:nnN`, since the former is much faster, and in this case you don't need a regular expression at all.

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn
    \str_new:N \l__crypto_code_str
    
    \cs_new_protected:Npx \__cryptocode_process_string:
      {
        \str_replace_all:Nnn \exp_not:N \l__crypto_code_str { ~ } { , }
        \str_replace_all:Nnn \exp_not:N \l__crypto_code_str
          { \char_generate:nn { 13 } { 12 } } { + }
      }
    \NewDocumentCommand\cryptocode{+v}{
        \str_set:Nn \l__crypto_code_str {#1}
        \__cryptocode_process_string:
        \par
        Result:
        \par
        \str_use:N \l__crypto_code_str
    }
\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}

\cryptocode{X H C M O N O Y J F O C D L D
T Z L O B O T O Q L O T H Y F
O M W M C L F V S R V L R G I
V Y C Y P O D Y R D X M I E Z
E K O D V J D E C A B R A E O
J B N X L V P R I L V A C A A
A A E V V G J C I R A Q U Y D
W L J S P B B G L L Y B A N I
G L O F C P Z V S K O G E L F
A E C L E A T O V P U D J J K
T N H M R T B R R T I C Z A A
O A G V A F W A R R O F R P B
R I J S N B F O L E O Z G E J
T Q R W A U T E O L N I D R W
G B J L E Y C G E C O P M X J}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This works well and it is easy to follow but even with `+v` "my regex" does not work. Why?

Comment: @projetmbc Because TeX translates newlines into character 13 (carriage return) on input, and doesn't use character 10 (newline) in the tokenisation, so you'd have to use `\r` in your regular expression instead.

Comment: If it is done whatever the encoding of the file is, that's good news. Thanks for all.

Comment: @projetmbc one can change which character TeX inserts at the end of each line (through `\endlinechar`), but with the usual settings this is set to 13 (and `+v` should normalise those, iirc).

Comment: Ok. I was thinking of normal use cases.